# Can i able add new bar code type for AVCaptureMetadataOutput.metadataObjectTypes in iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, barcode

I am currently building barcode application but `AVCaptureMetadataOutput.metadataObjectTypes` doesn't support required barcode type, which is required for application.

Currently iOS support following barcode types:

```
AVMetadataObjectTypeUPCECode,
AVMetadataObjectTypeCode39Code,

AVMetadataObjectTypeCode39Mod43Code,
AVMetadataObjectTypeCode93Code,
AVMetadataObjectTypeCode128Code,
AVMetadataObjectTypeEAN8Code,
AVMetadataObjectTypeEAN13Code,
AVMetadataObjectTypeAztecCode,
AVMetadataObjectTypePDF417Code,
AVMetadataObjectTypeQRCode
```

Then how I should add new barcode type code like `AVMetadataObjectTypeCustom111Code`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

no. there is no api for that.

you need to use a different SDK for this or write it all by hand